# How to declare a dynamic array of structure pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am creating a Graph using an Adjacency List.

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    int value;
    int to;
} node;

typedef struct bag
{
    node *first;
    int size;
} bag;
```

A `node` is each edge in the graph and a `bag` is the list of all the adjacent edges to a vertex.

I would like to create a data structure `Adjacency List` such that the list is an array of **`bag *`**.
Something like this -

```
bag **adjacency_list;
```

However I am confused about how to initialize the `adjacency_list`.

I would like my `adjacency_list's` size to be equal to the number of vertices with the capability of adding more vertices in future if need be.

If I initialize as following -

```
adjacency_list = malloc(no_vert * sizeof(*adjacency_list));
```

How would I be able to add the corresponding bags (edges) for each vertex?
[image]

Comment: How to declare an array or structure pointers: `node* adjacency_list[size];`. But you seem to be asking how to dynamically allocate one.

Comment: Yes, I want to declare it dynamically, as I want the capability to add a new vertex when needed.

Comment: So, ask that question. Not "How to declare an array of structure pointers?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need linked list, there is no need from double pointer. I.e. define `bag * adjacency_list;`.

Comment: If I declare it just as a `Linked List`, to access a vertex I will have to scan through the entire list. I want the access to be kind of like an array. for e.g.:`bag* vertex_bag = adjacency_list(vertex * sizeof(bag *))`.

Comment: To allocate objects for double pointer, you have to first `malloc( N_elements * sizeof (element) );`, then malloc memory for each object. The problem is if you need to extend the root array.

Comment: Did something like this - `bag *bag_of_vertex;  
adj_list* adjacency_list = (adj_list *) malloc(no_vert * sizeof(adj_list));  
bag_of_vertex = (bag *) malloc(sizeof(bag));  
*(adjacency_list + i * sizeof(adj_list)) = bag_of_vertex;` and it works fine. However, I realize that this would not make the list dynamic.